# UITabBarController on iOS8 broken for smaller screens

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

It seems using UITabBarController on 3,5inch screens is causing problems since IOS8.
I'm using the UITabBarController as a root controller, each tab has its own viewController. The issue is when returning from a modal viewController, the tabBar disappears.
This only occurs on IOS8 with a smaller screen (3,5inch) and has always worked on older versions of IOS.

Anyone an idea how to fix this?

```
//AppDelegate.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

//----------------------------------------------- 

//AppDelegate.m
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

//Set each tab to show an appropriate view controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:mainViewController,aViewController,bViewController, nil]];
self.tabBarController = tabBarController;

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

// Finally, add the tab controller view to the parent view
[window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController.navigationController;
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


//----------------------------------------------- 

//launching a modal viewController from the mainViewController
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:listViewController];        
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];  

//dismissing the modal viewController 
//listViewController.m
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

//after returing to the mainViewController the tabBar at the bottom of the screen just dissapears
```

Comment: There are several problems in your code, but I'm not sure any of them is causing your problem. The window shouldn't be an IBOutlet, I don't know whether your tab bar controller should be or not; do you have a tab bar controller in a storyboard? You shouldn't add the tab bar controller's view as a subview -- adding the tab bar controller as the window's root view controller already does that. At the end, you set the window's root view controller again which makes no sense, especially since you're setting it to self.tabBarController.navigationController which doesn't exist as far as I can tell.

Comment: I tried to remove the double assigning and the IBOutlet but it did not make any differenc. I don't use storyboards or xib files, it is all done in code.